# How to read keyboard and mouse presses in C# .netcore

Tags: c#, input

I want to capture keyboard and mouse inputs from my application(not from console.readline) and need it to be multi platform. I have seen solutions that work for windows but i dont know if they would work on linux.

What is the correct way to capture keyboard and mouse presses?

Comment: The only cross-platform programs in .NET Core are console-mode programs. WPF and WinForms programs are inherently not cross platform.

Comment: @Dai Yes, i know that, i want to capture keyboard input outside of console, without the user sending input through the terminal window, thats why i said not from readline. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env & data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of screens, & user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you likely want the following:

```
Console.KeyAvailable
Console.ReadKey
```

these let you see if a key is available ( non blocking ) and then to be able to read that key.

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netcore-3.1

as for the mouse, I don't think you can do this cross platform.

If you are talking about hooking the system calls for keyboard and mouse so you can see all keyboard and mouse activity, then there is no cross platform way to do this.

Comment: "If you are talking about hooking the system calls for keyboard and mouse so you can see all keyboard and mouse activity" - if the host system has a *nix style filesystem and exposes USB hardware events via a file in a consistent format (e.g. `/dev/input/event*`), then the OP's program could use that - they'd need WSL on Windows, of course.